# Mixing C++ and C# projects in VS Express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working a hobby project that is a file parsing library written in straight C.  I have the library and a command line interface building and running on several Unix-type platforms.  I also have a simple Cocoa app that uses the library for OS X.  I would like to have a simple .net app for Windows as well.  In order to do this, I need to mix a c project (the library), a c++/cli project (the .net wrapper) and a c# project (the app) in a single solution.  Is this possible with Visual Studio Express?  Or do I have to pay $800 for Visual Studio Pro?

jorj

Comment: I think the main feature you will need is the Visual Studio Configuration Manager, in order to specify for each project if you want to build AnyCPU for managed projects in your solution, and win32 or x64 for unmanaged projects. Aside from that, good knowledge of how to call unmanaged code, from managed code.

Comment: At work, we have VS2010 Ultimate and having C++ and C# projects within a solution is no problem.  In VS2010 Express, when I try to add a C++ project to a solution with a new C# app, it isn't allowing it.  Is there some trick to make this work or is it just not possible in the Express edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Express editions are restricted so that you cannot mix and match projects from one language inside the IDE for a different language.

To check this, I just tried to include a VC++ 2010 project into a VC# 2010 solution, and the GUI prevents this. It fails the other way too.

Note that there is nothing to stop you doing all the work in the free versions and cross-referencing the resulting binaries and libraries.  You just can't build a single solution from a mixed-language set of projects.